# SPDIF audio input to identify stream type

Tags: audio

I have two related questions:
1) What are the options for adding an SPDIF Audio input to a Raspberry Pi (Toslink optical, or coax)? 
2) What software and libraries are available that can decode and parse the various types of streams that can be carried over SPDIF (PCM, AC-3, DTS, DD+, etc)

I'm trying to make a tool to identifying digital audio formats, not a playback device or D/A.